# Showing $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \longrightarrow x \in X \Leftrightarrow \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n>N: x_n =x$

Tags: general-topology

Let's have $X$ an infinite topological space with the following topology:

$$\tau = \{\emptyset, X\} \cup \{U \subset X \, | \, X\setminus U \text{ is  finite  or  countable}\}$$

I already proved that it's topology. Now I need to prove the following thing: A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x \in X$, if and only if $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n > N: x_n = x$. I already proved the "$\Leftarrow$" way, which is obvious. Now I need to prove the "$\Rightarrow$", but I can't seem to find any approach. Any hints?

Comment: Do it indirectly. Take a sequence that is not eventually constant, and find a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that no tail of the sequence is contained in $V$.

Comment: So, I assume $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not eventually constant, so I can take the open set: $$V := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N} : x_n \neq x} x_n$$

$V$ is countable $\Longrightarrow V^c is open$ and $x \in V^c$. Then I have a neighbourhood of $x$ that doesn't contain all the $x_n \neq x$. But still, it could be that every $10^{th}$ $x_n$ for instance is equal to $x$.

Comment: Well, then $x$ is an accumulation point of the sequence, but the sequence is still not convergent.

Comment: Couldn't it converge to $x$, having regularly some $x_n = x$? Like if took a convergent sequence $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and then made out of it a new series $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that is like $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, but where at every $10^{th}$ $n$ I replace $x_n$ by $x$.?

Comment: Look at the definition of convergence for sequences again. A sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $b$ if *for all neighbourhoods* $W$ *of* $b$ there is an index $n_W\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n \in W$ for all $n \geqslant n_W$. The sequence must at some point never again leave $W$. Here, the neighbourhood is constructed so that the sequence always leaves $W$. Perhaps only for a short time, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: So if I assume that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converg, and construct $V$ as above, then $V^c$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. Then there must be an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that  $\forall n > n_0: x_n \in V^c$, which then must all be $x_n = x$, and that means then, that $\forall n > n_0: x_n = x$. Doesn't that finish the proof?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got there in the comments, here's a re-arranged version.

Let $V = \{x_n: x_n \ne x\}$ then $O = X \setminus V$ is an open set in $\tau$ and it contains $x$.

Since $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence there is $N$ such that for $n \gt N$ all $x_n \in O$.

Therefore for $n \gt N$ all $x_n \not\in V \implies x_n = x$, i.e $(x_n)$ is eventually constant.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a finite set endowed with the topology given above, show that $\tau = \mathcal{P}(X)$, i.e., $X$ is discrete. Then, the result holds for any discrete space. Of course, if $X$ is infinite, then if the collection is still a topology, it may not be discrete anymore.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. It's supposed to be an infinite $X$. Later there is a question, where $X$ is countable, in which case it is the discrete topology. But for now, it's only infinite.